# React: css animation

Tags: css, reactjs

I want every time new user prepend, first div have css animation, but my code only work on first prepend, second time prepend animation not trigger

```js
const [userList, setUserList] = useState<any>([]);
<div className='user-listing absolute top-0 left-0'>
    {
        userList.map((user:any, index:number)=>{
        return (
            <div key={index} className='user'>{user}</div>
        )
        })
    }
</div>
<button onClick={()=> setUserList((list:any) => [randomUser(),...list])}>
  add
</button>
```

```scss
.user-listing{
  .user{
    &:first-child {
      animation-name: fadeIn;
      animation-duration: .15s;
    }
  }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
      opacity: 0;
      transform: scale(.2)
  }

  to {
      opacity: 1;
      transform: scale(1)
  }
}
```

Comment: You are only applying the CSS rules on the `first-child`.. Try move the `animation-name` and `animation-duration` out of the `:first-child` selector

Comment: but as I mentioned in my question, I want the first div to have the css animation, meaning everytime prepend new user is consider first div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happening is that the `key` prop remain the same in the first element of the list, so React will update the elements containing the existing keys and will create a new one at the end of the list with a new key.

At first you have an element with the key 0 that is new, so the animation will play. Then, you add an element in your user list, but in the DOM the element with the key 0 will remain at the top of the list, so it won't be a new element to the DOM, it will be the same element updated with the name of the new user. The new element will be the one with the key 1 (and will be create with the data of the already existing user) etc...

That is why it is not a good idea to use the indexes of an array as keys.

So if you want your animation to be played for every new element prepended to the array, you must use a unique key that identify the user (its id for example, it is the best option, or its name). In you case, the user seems to only be a `string`, so maybe you should just use it like this :

```js
userList.map((user: any) => {
  return (
    <div key={user} className='user'>{user}</div>
  )
})
```

Hope it's clear :)